# can git be run with less file permissions than the files it tracks?

Tags: linux, macos, git, sudo, chmod

here is the situation: i want to use git to track a directory of preference files that are owned by root.

it would be nice if git commands that don't modify the files (like `git status` and `git diff`) can be run as the user (without `sudo`).

through the following steps, i've created a repo that seems to function in a reasonable manner:

```
sudo mkdir .git
sudo chmod <user>:<group> .git
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

i can run `git status` and `git diff` as the user. `git checkout ...` and `git reset ...` fail as the user, but *seem* to run fine when prefixed with `sudo`.

this seems perfect: no `sudo` needed to get into the repo and take a look at what's gone on, but to change the tracked files requires an extra level of effort, as it should for system files.

the question is: will this cause me any problems with how git is reading and writing files inside the `.git` directory? will any commands i need `sudo` to run end up creating things inside `.git` with `root` permission that will then cause problems trying to run commands that don't modify the tracked files as the user?

thanks and advance for any answers.

Comment: The first step could be to have the `.git` repository in a directory you own and then always pass `--git-dir` to `git` commands or have an alias.

Comment: thanks @pmr, i wasn't aware of the `--git-dir` option; i'll check that out. as i said above, it *seems* to be working well now, but i don't know much about git internals and have no idea if running commands as two different users with different privilege levels will cause a conundrum down the line.